# background color for text box won't change

Tags: html, css, background-color

I have the following code where I want to place a text box over an image. The text overlays the image but when I set the background color to white, it still appears transparent. I have done this before but for some reason it's not working here. Any help would be appreciated.

```
    <section>
        <h1 style="margin-left: 10%;">Blah, blah</h1>
        <img src="_images/some.jpg" style="margin-left: 10%; width: 60%;" >
        <section style="margin-left: 45%; margin-top: -35%; background-color: #FFF; padding: 1em; width: 20%;">
            <p style="font-size: 2em; margin-top: -5%;">More blah, blah.</p>
            <p style="font-size: 1.2em; ">Even more blah, blah.</p>
        </section>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the position on the inner section element to relative.

```html
<section>
        <h1 style="margin-left: 10%;">Blah, blah</h1>
        <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/34950/pexels-photo.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350" style="margin-left: 10%; width: 60%;" >
        <section style="position: relative; margin-left: 45%; margin-top: -35%; background-color: #FFF; padding: 1em; width: 20%;">
            <p style="font-size: 2em; margin-top: -5%;">More blah, blah.</p>
            <p style="font-size: 1.2em; ">Even more blah, blah.</p>
        </section>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
background-color: #FFF;
```

use this

```
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
```

Comment: Why would that change anything? It's just leaning on the fact that the background could be white. If it ever changed, the 0 opacity would make it so that it isn't white anymore...